# Difference in Request and Response bytes for Cloudrun service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, micronaut

I have just built a very sample Hello REST App using Micronaut to test out GCP Cloud Run service. The packaged container is built using `./gradlew dockerBuild` and uploaded to Artefactory registry of GCP.

CloudRun service has been configured to use 2 CPU 2 GB RAM and allowed 1000 concurrency per container. The service has been exposed publicly using GCP Load Balancer.

While performing load tests, I observed that there is a considerable difference in request and response size (bytes) logged by CloudRun and the sizes logged in Fiddler. I used apache bench for performance testing and then for debugging this issue used Postman and Fiddler.

Following image shows the sizes logged by CloudRun,

[image]

following is from Fiddler

[image]

The difference is pretty high almost 2x for request and 3x for response.

What could be the reason of such mismatch, any help / pointers appreciated.

*UPDATE* : After turning on Load balancer logs, I could see that the bytes are matching.

[image]

Looks like LB and CloudRun are having some overhead while communicating internally.

Comment: You must review the actual difference and not just bytes transferred. The load balancer will add headers such as **X-Forwarded-For** and a few others for tracking/tracing

Comment: Can you share the response headers? I suppose a compressed response: the size is 647, but the effective byte transferred (compressed) is 215. The compression ratio is fair.

Comment: 215 are not compressed bytes, I manually verified. I will try to turn on request response logging at Cloudrun / Micronaut level.

Comment: I completely agree with @JohnHanley . I think the more important thing is to examine the contents of the request/response and headers and look at what is actually different. You could do this by passing payloads with fixed byte sizes and have them manually log the headers and payload to compare the differences.